# Undefined method sort_by in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I am facing issues while using sort or sort_by in my presenter and controller. It says undefined method 'sort_by' .

Does it belong to any particular class? I have looked it up online but I am not able to find anything concrete.

Can any one shed light on this?

Here is my presenter code-

```
def sortDocument()
    @list.sort do |a, b|
      (b.published_date <=> a.published_date) ||
      a.display_name <=> b.display_name
      @list
end
```

and alternatively

```
def sortDocument()
  @list.sort_by!{ |m| m.published_date }
end
```

EDIT:

Error message:

```
undefined method `sort_by!' for #<DocumentsBureauServices::DocumentList:0x007ff8250f8a28>
```

presenter-

```
class DocumentPresenter

  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
    @list = sort_document()
  end
 def sortDocument()
    @list.sort do |a, b|
      (b.published_date <=> a.published_date) ||
      a.display_name <=> b.display_name
      @list
 end
end
```

and alternatively

```
 def sortDocument()
      @list.sort_by!{ |m| m.published_date }
    end
```

Comment: Your presenter/controller code and error message and backtrace required. I bet nil error.

Comment: I just added the code. I am not inheriting any classes in my presenter for your information.

Comment: `@list` is `nil` probably. Where and how do you set it? Also, I advice you to stick with Ruby naming convention - `def sort_document` instead of `def sortDocument()`.

Comment: '@list' is not empty. I am accessing '@list' from the initialize function in the same presenter. Also, I just tried to display all the data in list and I was able to do so. So, it is definitely not nil

Comment: Ok then, show your error message and *whole* content of your presenter and how you use it.

Comment: Just added it in the EDIT in my question. Please refer

Comment: You simply don't have `sort_by` method defined for `DocumentList` class, which instance you hold in `@list`.

Comment: I am sorry could you be more clear? I was under the impression that sort_by is a method provided by rails. I have added both the possible code I would use for the function. 'sort' and 'sort_by' is not getting recognised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78161/discussion-between-alex-jose-and-marek-lipka).

Comment: It is - but only for classes that have `Enumerable` module mixed in. It seems your `DocumentList` class doesn't have `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorts enum using a set of keys generated by mapping the values in enum through the given block...to use **[sort_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by)** ...

```
%w{ apple pear fig }.sort_by {|word| word.length}
              #=> ["fig", "pear", "apple"]
```

Comment: Please check my question again. I did the same. @list has a JSON hash of data

Comment: then..@list is nil...please check

Comment: I checked the same. It is not nil. I am able to display @list values

Comment: Hey! I figured it out. The mistake was that @list has a hash of data in it in which there exists an element 'document'.To correctly use it. I need to access the same by - @list.document.sort_by() . Terribly silly mistake. Thanks a ton though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DocumentsBureauServices::DocumentList` doesn't include the enumerable module and doesn't have access to the sort_by method.

If indeed DocumentList is a decorator around an enumerable object then you could use a delegator. ActiveSupport has a method dedicated to delegating: http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

In your case, you could use it like this:

```
class DocumentsBureauServices::DocumentList

  delegate :sort_by!, to: :my_enumerable

  def initialize(enumerable)
    @my_enumerable = enumerable
  end

end
```

And then you could call sort_by! on your list object like this:

```
@list = DocumentsBureauServices::DocumentList.new(Document.all)
@list.sort_by! {|m| m.published_date}
#=> [#Document1, #Document2, etc]
```

If you want to know more about creating your own presenters, might I suggest the excellent RailsCast about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

I personally use the Draper library for presenters: https://github.com/drapergem/draper which makes presenting ActiveRecord objects a breeze. There's a RailsCast about it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper